# Generic functions for generic types in F#

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I'm learning functional programming with F#, and I want to write a function to raise number to power. I wrote it in the following manner:

```
let raiseToPower a power = 
    let folding x _ = x * a
    [1..power-1] |> List.fold folding a

let result = raiseToPower 2 5
```

I did not specify the type of an input variable `a`, so I can possibly use this function with float or integer number - but not the both

`let result = raiseToPower 2.3 5  // OK`

`// separate program
 let result = raiseToPower 2 5    // OK`

`// separate program
 let result1 = raiseToPower 2.3 5 // OK
 let result2 = raiseToPower 2 5   // fail`

*The first question is:*
    **Is there a way to make it generic?**

---

The reason I made a function for something F# already has a built-in implementation is that I want to use something like that with custom type - Complex Numbers, for instance.

Consider the following:

```
type ComplexNumber = {re: double; im: double;}

let (@*) cn1 cn2 = 
    {re = cn1.re * cn2.re - cn1.im * cn2.im; im = cn1.re * cn2.im + cn1.im * cn2.re}
```

I have a new type `ComplexNumber` and a new operator for it that multiplies two complex numbers. Now I can write a similar function to raise `ComplexNumber` to power:

```
let raiseCnToPower a power = 
    let folding x _ = x @* a
    [1..power-1] |> List.fold folding a
```

*So the second question is:*
    **Is there a way to make the initial function to work with custom types and custom operators?**

---

*Conclusive question:*
    **I'd like to know what you should do here in terms of functional programming. Is this considered to be a problem, or different functions for different types doing almost the same is OK? Is there a way to improve solution in terms of functional programming and F# specifically?**

Comment: In case you haven't seen them already, [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/operator-overloading) [pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/generics/statically-resolved-type-parameters) of F# docs might help, as well as checking out the [source code of FSharpPlus](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpPlus).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy way is to declare it `inline`:

```
let inline raiseToPower a power = 
    let folding x _ = x * a
    [1..power] |> List.fold folding (a / a) // <- handles power = 0

let result1 = raiseToPower 2 5
let result2 = raiseToPower 2. 5
```

Comment: Why does this help?

Comment: `let inline raiseToPower a power = List.replicate power a |> List.fold ( *) LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne` handles also power = 0, albeit not < 0. Compare with `pown`.

Comment: Hey, AMieres! Thanks for answer! I have a consequent question: if `inline` works in F# the same way it works in, for example, C++, and compiler just replicates function every time it is used, doesn't it make it a bad solution? And what functional programming in general has to say about `inline` in general?

Comment: @DmitryVolkov `inline`does expand at the point of call, but it is much more powerful. By doing so, it propagates member constraints of any generic arithmetic operator used. It is also contagious.

Comment: As far as I know FP in general is indifferent to the use of `inline`. Overuse of them can make debugging harder. For generic arithmetic operations they are a simple and effective solution. The alternative is to use constraints, but those turn out to be much harder to implement.